# bond0 and xen = crash

Tags: linux, networking, xen, rhel5, bonding

Bonding with xen
1 - Stop all guests. Reboot dom0 after running "chkconfig xend off" and "chkconfig xendomains off".
2 - Configure bond0 by enslaving eth0 and eth1 to it. I added the below two entries to /etc/modprobe.conf.

alias bond0 bonding
options bond0 mode=6,miimon=100

Content of /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

DEVICE=eth0
USERCTL=no
ONBOOT=yes
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
BOOTPROTO=none

Content of /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1

DEVICE=eth1
USERCTL=no
ONBOOT=yes
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
BOOTPROTO=none

Content of /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0

DEVICE=bond0
IPADDR=
NETMASK=
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
USERCTL=no

Did "modprobe bond0" and "service network restart" after that.

3 - Edit /etc/xen/xend-config.sxp

Change

(network-script network-bridge)

To

(network-script 'network-bridge netdev=bond0')

4 - Start xend. "service xend start".

5 - chkconfig xend on.

6 - modprode bond0

7 - more /proc/net/bonding/bond0

8 - Create guest images as usual and bridge it to xenbr0.

about config i did for my xen kernel rhel 5.3 after i reboot the host server i get in place bond0 get pbond0 and its get disconnect from network only i ping to my vm's on the host server any one have any idea why xen bond0 is acting like that or what is solutions to come out of pbond0 to bond0.

Comment: Please state your question. Mark it with a question mark. Please use punctuation in your paragraphs. Maybe then we can figure out what you are asking.

Comment: pls ignore my english skill and writen step by bcoz i'm just try head with same thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think I had the same problem but it is hard to know without seeing the stack trace from the kernel oops. I think mine was related to a driver issue. Bonding with xen crashed the machine. I found a bug report from RedHat on this. Upgrading to kernel-2.6.18-160.el5.x86_64.rpm or newer fixed it. You can get -160 from:

http://people.redhat.com/dzickus/el5/160.el5/x86_64/

Try this out and see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: thanks i m using kernel-2.6.18-164.el5.x86_64.rpm i got fix that.